# When i change screen in Libgdx, it instantly turns back

Tags: screen, libgdx

I have 2 screens and wish to be able to move between them. One opens on load and this one is called gameScreen. the other is called Another. The game doesn't do anything. i'm just playing with libgdx. This is my code

main class which opens gameScreen

the main class, MyGdxGame, contains this

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.me.mygdxgame.gameScreen;

public class MyGdxGame extends Game{

public gameScreen game;

@Override
public void create() {  
    game = new gameScreen(this);
    setScreen(game);
    }
}
```

gameScreen is

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;

public class gameScreen extends Game implements Screen{

OrthographicCamera camera;
 private MyGdxGame game;

 public Another game2;


public gameScreen (MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game=game;
    camera=new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true,1080,1920);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1F, 1F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



    camera.update();

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        game2=new Another(this);
        setScreen(game2);

    }

}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

and Another is

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Another extends Game implements Screen{

OrthographicCamera cameraa;
SpriteBatch batch;
Sprite hello;
Texture thello;




private gameScreen game;

public Another(gameScreen game){
    this.game=game;
    cameraa=new OrthographicCamera();
    cameraa.setToOrtho(true,1080,1920);
    batch=new SpriteBatch();


    thello = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
    thello.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    hello = new Sprite(thello);
    hello.flip(false, true);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    cameraa.update();


    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){


    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cameraa.combined);
    cameraa.update();

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(hello,0,0);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

}
```

i used rather unusual names such as cameraa and gamee. this is because this whole project is a test, like i said i i couldnt be bothered setting proper names

Comment: Not enough code. What is "Another"? also how can you use setScreen method like that, are you extending game on the screens too?

Comment: @Lestat sorry. Another is the other screen. And they all extend Game, yes

Comment: You shouldnt make them extend Game. Only implement Screen. show the complete code of the 3 classes and I will answer with the solution

Comment: @Lestat okay, ive updated question with full code. Thanks for help, would be grateful if you could solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in your screens (gameScreen and Another) delete "extends Game", only leave implements Screen.

Then instead of using setScreen(game2) like that in gameScreen. Use it like this:

game.setScreen(game2)   //add "game."

thats because your screen wont extend from game, but you get the game in that field, so you can use it from it.

And only as an extra: dont call the Another instance "game2" because it is not a game. And dont use lowercase letter to begin the name of a class (gameScreen should be GameScreen), but thats only convention, up to you if you do it.

Comment: Okay this works just as expected. The problem is, it doesn't seem to work if i open a fourth screen from the third one. say the thirs screen is called EndScreen. and im opening it from Another. Should EndScreen have a private MyGdxGame game; or private Another game; ?

Comment: all your screens need a MyGdxGame,which you will send from one screen to the next (sothere is actually just one instance).

Comment: (MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game=game; ----this. I notice in your Another you receive a "gameScreen" which is wrong

Comment: Okay, this doesnt seem to work. It seems if you open Another from gameScreen, Another needs to have private gameScreen game; not private MyGdxGame;

Comment: gameScreen is not a game, and you shouldnt pass it as a parameter. Pass the actual game (MyGdxGame). Just make sure you set it correctly in the screens constructors and fields, exactly as you do in gameScreen.